# CSS Border Colour wont change, tried everything

Tags: html, css

I have today started to use CSS styling, one thing i cant figure out to change colour of border on a label, i tried alot of examples from stackoverflow with no success. The label in question is on https://www.donermeister.co.uk/product/doner-kebab-beef/ on the right side, once label is selected I want the border to change colour, what ive tried is:

```
.ywapo_selected {
  border: 15px solid green;
}
```

with no sucess, would appreciate any help. I can check the bacground colour, the text eveyrthing just not the border, its so frustrating

Comment: There doesnt appear to be anything on the site you linked.

Comment: i apologise, check now @ChristopherNgo

Comment: No worries! What is the element in question? I dont see anything appended with that css class.

Comment: @ChristopherNgo its the label on the right side, the 4, i want the dark grey border of them to change colour when selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you also defined this:

```
.ywapo_input_container.ywapo_input_container_labels.ywapo_selected {
     border-color: #999595;
}
```

This has a very high-level of specificity, which essentially just means, the more exact a selector is, the higher chances that styling gets applied.

For this to execute, you need to set an even higher level of importance:

You can do any of the following:

1) use an !important keyword with your selector, not great practice but it gets the job done.

```
.ywapo_selected {
    border: 15px solid #green !important
}
```

2) have an equally specific selector, better CSS practice:

```
.ywapo_input_container.ywapo_input_container_labels.ywapo_selected{
    border: 15px solid #green
}
```

Comment: Please don't use `!important`. That is like tossing a grande at a piñata.

Comment: Yeah I was just getting to that haha . :) @Intervalia thank you.

Comment: that worked, thank u very much, learned something after trying for 2 hours

Comment: @sakow0 you're very welcome! Please also consider my 2nd solution, which is better CSS practice.